# p4python vs. calling p4 using subprocess, which way performs better?

Tags: python, performance, perforce

As title.

I noticed that calling `p4` from the `subprocess` module is not very fast. But I hesitate learning the Perforce Python binding without knowing whether or not it performs better.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could share the experience of trying both.

**EDIT**

I observed this on Win10/desktop PC where my working copy is on an SSD drive. The commands I observed include `add`, `edit`, and `reconcile` over a large number of files and folders. I didn't do rigorous profiling but the perceived response from `subprocess` seems slower than the same operation in P4V.

Sam Stafford's answer makes sense if the `p4` calls induce multi-connection overhead.

Comment: What command are you running that is "not very fast", and how can you tell? If the command is `p4 sync`, then whether you run it by spawning `p4` or by invoking an API is not going to matter, but if the command is `p4 fstat //some/specific/file` then maybe it might. Also, what platform are you on? That is really important for automation programming like this.

Comment: When you run, say, `p4 edit` over many files, do you run `p4 edit` separately for each file or run `p4 edit` once with many filename arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, using a p4 API is going to be faster than using the CLI, with the most dramatic gains apparent if you're running multiple commands, since the API lets you easily run multiple commands on a single server connection whereas the CLI binary establishes a connection for each invocation.

Comment: I suppose. I'm skeptical, to tell you the truth. I think the primary determinant for picking the api is that it's easier to write a complex script that has to parse and manipulate the p4 data structures if you use one of the scripting APIs. But I think the basic performance depends more on how you use the p4 features in question. For example, creating a new branch takes as long as it takes, whether you script it or run spawned p4 commands. Sure, the tcp connection and login handshake take a bit of time, but that's a wash if your problem is that `p4 sync -f //...` is slow.

Comment: The ("undocumented") `p4 -x CMDFILE run` command can also run commands using a single connection.